# jQuery replace url if it contains certain path

Tags: jquery

I want jQuery to search an HTML document and look for any links that contain a certain domain name, i.e.

https://www.mylivesite.com

And replace it with a local link, i.e.

demo.html

I know how to target all of the links with the external url using the *= (contains value) but I'm not sure how to construct the replace/replacewith?

I can't just do a simple replace as the https://www.mylivesite.com url may have other unknown directories on the end i.e. https://www.mylivesite.com/something

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="https://www.mylivesite.com"]').each(function() {
 //if the link contains the the above url, change it to demo.html which is local link.
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Regular expressions

Comment: Should you be using js to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: you should remove * after href

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `.replace` with a regular expression:

```
href.replace(/https:\/\/www.mylivesite.com\//, "demo.html");
```

This replaces www.mylivesite with demo.html, given your caveat that it may contain something else, you get that something else as well, eg:

```
demo.html/something
```

if you just want to replace the href, then there's no need for `.replace` or even the `.each`

```
$("a[href*='www.mylivesite.com']").attr("href", "demo.html");
```

Snippet replacing just the host:

```js
$("a[href*='www.mylivesite.com']").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("href", function(i, href) {
    return href.replace(/https:\/\/www.mylivesite.com/, "demo.html");
  });
});

// Demonstrate that href has changed by updating the caption
$("a").text(function(i, txt) {
  $(this).text($(this).attr("href"));
})
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='https://www.mylivesite.com/'></a>
<a href='https://www.mylivesite.com/something'></a>
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'></a>
```

Snippet replacing the whole url:

```js
$("a[href*='www.mylivesite.com']").attr("href", "demo.html");

// Demonstrate that href has changed by updating the caption
$("a").text(function(i, txt) {
  $(this).text($(this).attr("href"));
})
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='https://www.mylivesite.com/'></a>
<a href='https://www.mylivesite.com/something'></a>
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, It changed the url but also the name of the link

Comment: That's clearly there just to demonstrate that the url is changing - you don't take SO answers verbatim, you take what they are giving you.